# database relation on ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, relation

i have 5 tables
- USERS
- PRODUCTS 
- CATEGORIES
- ARTICLES
- COMMENTS

and i have 3 condition : 
- User can create category for products.
- Article can show comments.
- All products can be categorized to all categories and also all categories can have many products.

my question is what the relation type is required for each condition? (many to many, one to many, or one to one?) because i tried to learn from many source, but it still confusing my brain, no one could make me understand, perhaps u can help me, i very appreciate if u answer with a description why i should use that type of relation, THANKS :)

im new to program

Comment: To do your 3rd requirement you need an association table called for example category_products and for now you don't have it. Can you tell us where are id's ? It will tell you which association you should do.
That also means you need to have minimum 6 models. On for each tables you wrote previously + one for the new association table.

Comment: i have each 6 model for that, my question is, which the relation i use for each relation, many to many, one to one, ore one to many, just that, i asked bcoz i really dont understand with those variant, u can describe me why i should use that variant for each condition

Comment: I got it but we need to see where are the id's on your tables. Can you add this code to your description ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now with the details I have, I can suggest that:

```
#User
has_many :products
has_many :categories, through: :products

#Product
has_and_belongs_to_many :categories

#Category
has_and_belongs_to_many :product

#Article
has_many :comments
```

Comment: got it, but can u describe what "has_and_belongs_to_many" means? ill mark ur answer as done

Comment: That means each model needs the other and can have one or more items of each. 
You can take a look to [this documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has-many-through-and-has-and-belongs-to-many). It's very well describe and it's here that I've learnt associations. :-)